# How to click on the element with text as Edit?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to use Selenium WebDriver to click a button that has the following HTML code:

```
<a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl?id=400000&amp;e=T" 
id="edit_/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl?id=400000" 
aria-label="Edit Sales Order:300000 / 400000 ">Edit</a>
```

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[aria-label *= 'Edit Sales Order']")).click();
```

I need to identify by the Aria Label as all the other components either have duplicates or change w/ the number.

There must be something wrong with my CSS selector, but I can't figure it out.

Let me know if I should include the error codes, more info, or if I did something incorrect w/ the post.
Thanks!

**Edit: the aria label also changes and the location on the HTML also changes so I can't use xpath. DebanJanB's answer below clicks the element, but only when I manually hover over.**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.uir-item-edit[aria-label^='Edit Sales Order'][id*='transactions']"))).click();
```

Comment: Your code looks good. To be sure try it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp).

Comment: What the error you get?

Comment: Check If element is present inside any iframe?

Comment: DebanJanB' answer clicks the element when I hover over it. So now I'm trying to figure out how to move the mouse over the element, but this seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Got the mouse to move to it, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Edit** you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.uir-item-edit[aria-label^='Edit Sales Order'][id*='transactions']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='uir-item-edit' and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Edit Sales Order')][contains(@id, 'transactions') and text()='Edit']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **class="uir-item-edit"**. In CSS selector you have to use whole value like: **Edit Sales Order:300000 / 400000**. Try this

Comment: Let me know if this Correct: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[aria-label *= 'Edit Sales Order:300000 / 400000 ']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

I can give you work around, I know you are looking answer for CSS but you can also try below xpath solution:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='uir-item-edit']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='uir-item-edit'][@aria-label]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label='Edit Sales Order:300000 / 400000']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Edit')]")).click();

Yes, please share more info of error , good luck

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespaces from your CSS selector before `*` and after `=` so that instead of `a[aria-label *= 'Edit Sales Order']` you would have `a[aria-label*='Edit Sales Order']`

Reproduced, fixed and testsd in http://try.jsoup.org/~x6PCZNOcp6NnwKPFJN-IdR5gkJk